# Compatibility of anytrading Gym environment with TF-Agents

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

All Gym/Gymnasium standard environments are compatible with TwnsorFlow RL agents, but when I tried to use TF-Agents with anytrading I get errors because some required methods and attributes seem to be missing. For instance
this code that is working  for CartoPole and other Gym environments

```
env = gym.make('stocks-v0') #, df=df_features, frame_bound=(5,100), window_size=5)

def my_process_data(env):
    start = env.frame_bound[0] - env.window_size
    end = env.frame_bound[1]
    prices = env.df.loc[:, 'Close'].to_numpy()[start:end]
    signal_features = env.df.loc[:, ['volume', 'volume_delta', 'day_of_the_week', 'US_market', 'EU_market', 'AS_market', 'POC_volume', 'DPOC_buy_volume', 'DPOC_sell_volume', 'short_CVD', 'impulsive_CVD', 'avg_short_CVD', 'middle_CVD', 'middle_impulsive_CVD', 'avg_middle_CVD', 'close_delta', 'open_delta', 'high_delta', 'low_delta', 'close_%_change', 'open_%_change', 'high_%_change', 'low_%_change', 'H_shadow', 'L_shadow', 'BBANDS_short_3devdown', 'BBANDS_short_dev_delta', 'BBANDS_short_dev_delta_rolling_mean_7', 'BBANDS_short_dev_delta_rolling_mean_14', 'BBANDS_middle_dev_delta', 'BBANDS_middle_dev_delta_rolling_mean_7', 'BBANDS_middle_dev_delta_rolling_mean_14', 'RSI_14', 'RSI_7', 'ATR', 'HT_sine', 'HT_leadsine', 'HT_sine_over_leadsine', 'mfdelta', 'mfsign', 'SAR_UP_DWN', 'SAR_UP_DWN_STRENGHT', 'short_CVD_over_CVD_mean', 'middle_CVD_over_CVD_mean', 'VWAP_over_POC_price', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_buy_price', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_sell_price', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_buy_price', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_sell_price', 'DPOC_buy_price_over_DPOC_sell_price', 'short_CVD_over_CVD_mean-1', 'middle_CVD_over_CVD_mean-1', 'VWAP_over_POC_price-1', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_buy_price-1', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_sell_price-1', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_buy_price-1', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-1', 'DPOC_buy_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-1', 'short_CVD_over_CVD_mean-2', 'middle_CVD_over_CVD_mean-2', 'VWAP_over_POC_price-2', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_buy_price-2', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_sell_price-2', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_buy_price-2', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-2', 'DPOC_buy_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-2', 'short_CVD_over_CVD_mean-3', 'middle_CVD_over_CVD_mean-3', 'VWAP_over_POC_price-3', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_buy_price-3', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_sell_price-3', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_buy_price-3', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-3', 'DPOC_buy_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-3', 'short_CVD_over_CVD_mean-4', 'middle_CVD_over_CVD_mean-4', 'VWAP_over_POC_price-4', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_buy_price-4', 'VWAP_over_DPOC_sell_price-4', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_buy_price-4', 'POC_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-4', 'DPOC_buy_price_over_DPOC_sell_price-4', 'high_%_change-1', 'low_%_change-1', 'open_%_change-1', 'close_%_change-1', 'high_%_change-2', 'low_%_change-2', 'open_%_change-2', 'close_%_change-2', 'high_%_change-3', 'low_%_change-3', 'open_%_change-3', 'close_%_change-3', 'high_%_change-4', 'low_%_change-4', 'open_%_change-4', 'close_%_change-4', 'high_%_change-5', 'low_%_change-5', 'open_%_change-5', 'close_%_change-5', 'impulsive_CVD_derivate', 'short_CVD_derivate', 'avg_short_CVD_derivate', 'middle_CVD_derivate', 'avg_middle_CVD_derivate', 'VWAP_derivate', 'volume_derivate', 'RSI_14_derivate', 'RSI_7_derivate', 'mama_derivate', 'impulsive_CVD_increasing', 'short_CVD_increasing', 'middle_CVD_increasing', 'avg_short_CVD_increasing', 'avg_middle_CVD_increasing', 'VWAP_increasing', 'RSI_14_increasing', 'RSI_7_increasing', 'doji', 'Engulfing', 'Marubozu', 'short_CVD_min_delayed', 'short_CVD_max_delayed', 'middle_CVD_min', 'middle_CVD_min_delayed', 'middle_CVD_max', 'middle_CVD_max_delayed', 'impulsive_CVD_min_delayed', 'impulsive_CVD_max_delayed', 'impulsive_CVD_derivate_min_delayed', 'impulsive_CVD_derivate_max_delayed', 'avg_short_CVD_min_delayed', 'avg_short_CVD_max_delayed', 'BBANDS_short_dev_delta_min_delayed', 'BBANDS_short_dev_delta_max_delayed', 'BBANDS_middle_dev_delta_min_delayed', 'BBANDS_middle_dev_delta_max_delayed', 'RSI_14_min_delayed', 'RSI_14_max_delayed', 'RSI_7_min_delayed', 'RSI_7_max_delayed', 'zero_crossing_short_CVD', 'zero_crossing_impulsive_CVD', 'zero_crossing_impulsive_CVD_derivate', 'zero_crossing_avg_short_CVD', 'H_shadow_mean_4', 'H_shadow_mean_7', 'H_shadow_mean_21', 'L_shadow_mean_4', 'L_shadow_mean_7', 'L_shadow_mean_21', 'high_delta_mean_4', 'high_shadow_mean_7', 'high_shadow_mean_21', 'low_shadow_mean_4', 'low_shadow_mean_7', 'low_shadow_mean_21', 'VWAP_mean_4_p_derivate', 'VWAP_mean_7_p_derivate', 'VWAP_mean_21_p_derivate', 'VWAP_mean_63_p_derivate', 'VWAP_mean_189_p_derivate', 'VWAP_mean_4_vs_7_delta', 'VWAP_mean_4_vs_21_delta', 'VWAP_mean_4_vs_63_delta', 'VWAP_mean_4_vs_189_delta', 'VWAP_mean_7_vs_21_delta', 'VWAP_mean_7_vs_63_delta', 'VWAP_mean_7_vs_189_delta', 'VWAP_mean_21_vs_63_delta', 'VWAP_mean_21_vs_189_delta', 'VWAP_mean_63_vs_189_delta', 'close_vs_VWAP_4', 'close_vs_VWAP_7', 'close_vs_VWAP_21', 'close_vs_VWAP_63', 'close_vs_VWAP_189', 'open_vs_VWAP_4', 'open_vs_VWAP_7', 'open_vs_VWAP_21', 'open_vs_VWAP_63', 'open_vs_VWAP_189', 'low_vs_VWAP_4', 'low_vs_VWAP_7', 'low_vs_VWAP_21', 'low_vs_VWAP_63', 'low_vs_VWAP_189', 'high_vs_VWAP_4', 'high_vs_VWAP_7', 'high_vs_VWAP_21', 'high_vs_VWAP_63', 'high_vs_VWAP_189', 'zigzag_trigger', 'CO/HL', 'CO_sign', 'HL_delta', 'CO_delta', 'CO_delta_ratio_-1', 'CO_delta_ratio_-2', 'CO_delta_ratio_-3', 'Bar_relative_POC_price', 'Bar_relative_VWAP_price', 'US_central_time_seconds', 'cumulative_volume_mean_delta', 'HL_rolling_fw_mean']].to_numpy()[start:end]
    return prices, signal_features


class MyForexEnv(StocksEnv):
    _process_data = my_process_data


env = MyForexEnv(df=df_features, window_size=512, frame_bound=(512, len(df_features)))

[...]


from tf_agents.environments import utils

utils.validate_py_environment(env, episodes=5)
env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(env)
```

returns this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[154], line 3
      1 features_n = df_features.shape[1]-4
      2 from tf_agents.environments import utils
----> 3 utils.validate_py_environment(env, episodes=5)
      5 env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(env)
      7 q_net = q_network.QNetwork(env.observation_spec(), 
      8                            env.action_spec(), 
      9                            fc_layer_params = (features_n, features_n*10, features_n/8), 
     10                            activation_fn = activation_function,
     11                            dropout_layer_params = None)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\utils.py:58, in validate_py_environment(environment, episodes, observation_and_action_constraint_splitter)
     52 def validate_py_environment(
     53     environment: py_environment.PyEnvironment,
     54     episodes: int = 5,
     55     observation_and_action_constraint_splitter: Optional[
     56         types.Splitter] = None):
     57   """Validates the environment follows the defined specs."""
---> 58   time_step_spec = environment.time_step_spec()
     59   action_spec = environment.action_spec()
     61   random_policy = random_py_policy.RandomPyPolicy(
     62       time_step_spec=time_step_spec,
     63       action_spec=action_spec,
     64       observation_and_action_constraint_splitter=(
     65           observation_and_action_constraint_splitter))

AttributeError: 'MyForexEnv' object has no attribute 'time_step_spec
```

Is it possible to use anytrading environment with TF-Agents?

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a code snippet that could potentially help.

The provided code introduces a GymWrapper class, specifically designed to adapt any (gym) environment for seamless integration with TF-Agents. By using this GymWrapper class, you can easily bridge the gap between anytrading and TF-Agents.

It ensures that all the required methods and attributes are properly implemented, enabling you to use TF-Agents in your anytrading environment.

Take a look at the code snippet below:

```
from tf_agents.environments.tf_py_environment import TFPyEnvironment
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts
from tf_agents.environments import py_environment
from tf_agents.specs import array_spec
import gym_anytrading.datasets as DS

class GymWrapper(py_environment.PyEnvironment):
    def __init__(self, gym_env):
        super(GymWrapper, self).__init__()
        self._gym_env = gym_env
        self._action_spec = self._get_action_spec()
        self._observation_spec = self._get_observation_spec()
    def _get_action_spec(self):
        action_space = self._gym_env.action_space
        if isinstance(action_space, gym.spaces.Box):
            return array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
                shape=action_space.shape,
                dtype=action_space.dtype,
                minimum=action_space.low,
                maximum=action_space.high
            )
        elif isinstance(action_space, gym.spaces.Discrete):
            return array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
                shape=(),
                dtype=action_space.dtype,
                minimum=0,
                maximum=action_space.n-1
            )
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported action space type: {type(action_space)}")

    def _get_observation_spec(self):
        observation_space = self._gym_env.observation_space
        return array_spec.ArraySpec(
            shape=observation_space.shape,
            dtype=observation_space.dtype
        )

    def action_spec(self):
        return self._action_spec

    def observation_spec(self):
        return self._observation_spec

    def _reset(self):
        return ts.restart(self._gym_env.reset())

    def _step(self, action):
        obs, reward, done, info = self._gym_env.step(action)
        if done:
            return ts.termination(obs, reward)
        else:
            return ts.transition(obs, reward)
env = gym.make('forex-v0', df=DS.FOREX_EURUSD_1H_ASK, window_size = 10, frame_bound=(10, len(DS.FOREX_EURUSD_1H_ASK) - 1), unit_side = 'right');

train_py_env = GymWrapper(env);
eval_py_env = GymWrapper(env);

train_env = TFPyEnvironment(train_py_env);
eval_env = TFPyEnvironment(eval_py_env);
```

Note:

Frame Bound: When using the frame_bound parameter, make sure to set it as frame_bound=(10, len(DS.FOREX_EURUSD_1H_ASK)-1). This ensures that the frame bounds align with the size of your anytrading dataset. Deviating from this format might result in errors. (When I have used frame_bound=(10, 300) I have recived an error.

Resetting the Environment: It's important to call train_env.reset() at the beginning or end of your training loop to properly initialize the environment's state. This ensures that each episode starts with a clean state.